# Consulta sobre Connection Pool c#

Tags: c#, connection, pool

estoy intentando realizar un pool de conexiones a mi BD para la aplicación que estoy realizando,

actualmente mi cadena de conexión es inicializada de esta manera:

```
  public static AseConnection PruebaPool()
    {
        AseConnection conn;
        try
        {
            cadena = "Provider=Sybase ASE OLE DB Provider;Data Source=miSrv;Database=BDTest;Uid=SV;Pwd=123456;Min Pool Size=1;Max Pool Size=2;ConnectionReserveTimeout:10";
            conn = new AseConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = cadena;
            conectar = 1;
            return conn;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            conectar = 0;
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Esto esta funcionando para generar las conexiones correspondientes, pero al momento en que se supera el número de conexiones permitidas, mi applicación en vez de quedar en espera, esta deja de funcionar bloqueando cualquier procedimiento que se este realizando.

Esto de trabajar con `connection pool` es nuevo para mi, ya que siempre he trabajado con conexiones directas por cada solicitud.

Si alguien puede orientarme en como funciona el `connection pool` se lo agradecería, ya que toda la información que he encontrado es en como se configura la cadena de conexión y que **debería** hacer la aplicación en caso de superar el límite de conexiones disponibles dentro del pool, todo sin un ejemplo contundente en caso de superar las conexiones.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, ese post ya lo había revisado pero lo que necesito aclarar más es el "como evitar que mi aplicación se bloquee cuando supero el max pool size". o es que debo utilizar el código de la manera en que se describe en el post ?

Comment: Primero hay que revisar que se esté usando el pool correctamente. Luego de usar la conexión esta debe cerrarse para que sea liberada y pueda reusarse, en el post, las conexiones se usan dentro de bloques `using` de esa forma se cierran automáticamente después de usarlas. El pool de conexiones es dinámico, si no hay conexiones disponibles se crearán nuevas según se requieran. La base de datos influye también ya que esta es la que establece cuantas conexiones simultáneas pueden existir. En tu cadena de conexión está la opción `Max Pool Size=2` eso reduce a 2 el máximo de conexiones del pool.

Comment: exactamente la tengo limitada a 2 ya que como digo, al momento de ser superada esa cantidad, la aplicación se "bloquea" y deja de funcionar cualquier consulta que  esté o vaya a ser ejecutada, entonces quería saber si eso es normal, o la cadena del pool debería contener algo como "Incr Pool Size=10" para evitar que se bloquee por completo la aplicación ?

Comment: No es normal si la aplicación no hace más de dos peticiones simultáneas. Si se bloquea es porque las conexiones del pool no se están liberando después de usarlas y por eso la aplicación queda en espera de que el pool  tenga una conexión libre.

Comment: Agrega un conn. Close para liberar recursos

Comment: tambien, he revisado cada conn.Open() que tengo y todas luego de realizar el procedimiento o consulta necesario, cierro la conexión con el conn.Close(). Entonces más dudas me surgen al respecto. pondré un Ejemplo: tengo un procedimiento el cual busca facturas de los clientes, según el cliente que seleccione en un "select option" de mi formulario. entonces abro 2 navegadores y ejecuto el programa logeando con 2 cuentas diferentes del sistema, al dejar ejecutando ese procedimiento en la aplicación en ambas cuentas ya estoy ocupando las 2 conexiones disponibles en mi pool

Comment: y supuestamente la 3ra cuenta debería quedar como en "espera", c# me manda el error "se ha superado la cantidad de conexiones definidas en el pool, definir más" y como dice @Lobos no es normal que se bloquee todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejemplo para probar el pool de conexiones:

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var con = new SqlConnection("cadena de conexión; Max pool size = 2");
    con.Open();
    Console.WriteLine(con.State);

  }
}
```

En el código se intenta abrir diez conexiones, el tamaño máximo del pool es de 2, así que en consola se imprimirá lo siguiente:

```
Open
Open
```

Luego el programa quedará en espera durante un tiempo establecido por el timeout, después de eso producirá el error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  
The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  
This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and 
max pool size was reached.
```

Si dentro del tiempo de espera una conexión es liberada el programa continúa su ejecución como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var con = new SqlConnection("cadena de conexión; Max pool size = 2");
    con.Open();
    Console.WriteLine(con.State);
    LiberarConexion(con);
  }
}

static async void LiberarConexion(SqlConnection con) {
  Thread.Sleep(3000);
  con.Close();
}
```

Pasará lo mismo que con el código anterior, se abrirán dos conexiones y se imprimirá dos veces `Open`, luego el programa quedará en espera por una conexión libre pero esta vez una conexión será liberada cada tres segundos, como la espera es menor que el timeout el programa seguirá ejecutándose.

Espero que los ejemplos ayuden a entender mejor como funciona el pool de conexiones.

Comment: y con respecto al timeOut  que mencionas es el que especifico en mi cadena de conexión con el "ConnectionReserveTimeout:10" ?

Comment: Sí. Aunque no estoy seguro si funciona usando `:` en lugar de `=`.

Comment: le cambie el `:` por el `=` y probé abrir las conexiones con un `for` y al ejecutarlo con el `max pool size = 2` me lanza el error inmediatamente: `{"Cannot allocate more connections. Connection pool is at maximum. Increase Max Pool Size"}`

Comment: el tema es que estamos utilizando `sybase` y en infosybase dicen: `Note If Max Pool Size is specified, Data Provider restricts the maximum number of open connections to this value. The calls to AseConnection.Open() fail with AseException when this limit is reached.`

Comment: Bien, lo que faltaría entonces es abrir las conexiones dentro de un `try/catch` para que la aplicación no se detenga en caso se produzca un error con la conexión.